# one problem of creating table in latex

Tags: tables

I want to create a table in LaTeX by this

```
\begin{table}

\begin{center}‎‎‎‎

\begin{tabular}{‎c‎ | c | c | c | c ‎|c ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎{c}‎r}‎

‎j/i‎              & 1:Tumor & 2:Envir & 3:Leuk & 4:Lymph & 5:Macroph \\

\hline

Tumor &‎‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎1‎$‎&‎\pm‏ ‎1&‎\pm‏‎{‎1} ‎‎‎&‎\p‎m‏ ‎1  \\

Envir            &‎$‎‎‎1‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎‎$‎0‎$‎  \\

Leuk             &‎\pm‏ ‎1‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎  \\

Lymph          &‎\pm‏ ‎1&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎\$1$ \\‎

Macroph       &‎\pm‏ ‎1&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎$‎0‎$‎&‎‎‎$‎0‎$‎  \\‎‎‎‎‎‎

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{‎table}‎
```

but I have this table

[image]

what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: please always post complete documents that reproduce teh problem (also you can use the `{}` button to mark code sections)  `‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎{c}‎r` should be `cr` and `\pm‏ ‎1` should be in math mode `$\pm 1$`

Comment: something in this example appears to be related to the use of the arabic-indic numerals.  a complete example is really needed here to understand the context.

Answer (score 2):

If I edit the code according to [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)'s comment, everything seems fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    ‎j/i      & 1:Tumor  & 2:Envir & 3:Leuk & 4:Lymph & 5:Macroph \\
    \midrule
    Tumor    & 0        & 1 ‎& \(‎\pm1\) & \(\pm1\) & \(\pm1\) \\
    Envir    & 1        & 0 & 0        & 0        & 0 \\
    Leuk     & \(‎\pm1\) & ‎0 ‎& 0‎        & 0        & 0 \\
    Lymph    & \(‎\pm1\) & ‎0 ‎& 0‎        & 0        & \(‎\pm1\) \\
    Macroph  & \(‎\pm1\) & ‎0 ‎& 0‎        & 0        & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

I don't suppose the reason lies in the middle-european writing direction.
Please add more information and provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can help you better.

Comment: the problem in the original question appears to be somehow related to the fact that the numerals are "real" arabic ("arabic-indic") numerals.  without a complete minimum example, i don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's exactly what I wanted to show; `it works for me`.

Comment: no, you aren't showing what was asked for.  take a closer look at the shape of the digit preceding "Macroph".  the style of numerals wanted here can be specified only by @user60959; until a definitive specification is given, i think we have to take at face value what is visible in the example.  the only other question posted by this person (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196986/579) shows the same style of numerals, as footnote indices.  clearly, arabic is involved, but there's insufficient information to say more.

Comment: I wanted to show that the problem must lie in the arabic numbers or other details. When I boil it down to a middle-european minimal example, it works as I would have expected. Thus---as you say correctly---we need more information from @user60959.

Comment: my problem was solved by typed number in $$. Thanks a lot every body.